# Eigenvalues aren't given to be imaginary

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

So I have this matrix I am working with that looks like $$S=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -a & b\\ a & 0 & -c\\ -b & c& 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ and upon asking mathematica for the eigenvalues I get Eigenvlaues[S] $=0, \sqrt{-a^2+-b^2+-c^2},-\sqrt{-a^2+-b^2+-c^2} $. Yes the eigenvalues are imaginary, but why doesn't it simplify it to be imaginary, and how can I force it to replace those minus sines and slap an $i$ in there instead? When I go to find the Eigenvectors does it recognize the terms I have as imaginary eigenvalues and simplify as such, or do I need to force it somehow.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. -- Also, keep in mind `a`, `b`, and `c` are treated as *complex* numbers. -- Finally, something like this might work: `PowerExpand[Sqrt[-a^2]]`

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that! Okay thank you for the heads up. Could I just make the assumption in the code that a,b,c are all real?

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: Compare: `Simplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], a > 0 && b > 0]`,
`Simplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], a >= 0 && b >= 0]`,
`Simplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], {a, b} \[Element] Reals]`, `Simplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], a != 0 && b != 0 && {a, b} \[Element] Reals]` -- That the case `a == b == 0` seems important here looks like a weakness of Mathematica. It probably does not check whether the expression under the radical can change sign or not, probably for efficiency's sake.

Comment: Mma seems to want to treat `0` as a non-imaginary number and keep it separate from the (nonzero) imaginary numbers: `Assuming[a^2 + b^2 >= 0,
 FullSimplify@PiecewiseExpand@ComplexExpand[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2]]
 ]`

Comment: There is the, uh, hacky way to do this: `FactorI[expr_] := expr /. {HoldPattern[Power[Plus[s : (Times[-1, _] ..)], Rational[1, 2]]] :> I*Sqrt[Plus @@ Rest /@ {s}], HoldPattern[Power[Times[-1, s___], Rational[1, 2]]] :> I*Sqrt[Times[s]]}`; then `Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2] // FactorI` should give you what you want.